# Why if $LastExitCode=0 my SCHTASKS at CMD returns $?=False

Tags: powershell-4.0

This code works perfectly in returning scheduled tasks I'm looking for - but why does it send a False value for $?

```
SCHTASKS /Query /FO csv /v /s $Computer /U myuser /P 'mypass' | ConvertFrom-Csv | where {$_.TaskName -Like "*mytext*"}| Select TaskName , "Last Run Time", Author
$?
$LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a False value"? Keep in mind that the exit code `0` means, that everything is fine.

Comment: $? returns FALSE and $LASTEXITCODE returns 0 - so why is $? returning a FALSE if the SCHTASKS query is returning results ?